Not at fault vehicle accident - can I refuse to allow the car to be written off?
This is a simplified/fictionalized event to help me understand the law/my rights.   If jurisdiction matters, I am in New Zealand.
I have a vehicle which has sentimental value to me in excess of its insured/book value.   My car is rear ended and the other party is at fault.   The value of repairs is a about the value of the vehicle.    The other parties insurer - who I am dealing with directly - wants to pay the book value of the vehicle (and take possession of the vehicle and write it off).
I expect that writing the vehicle off is advantageous to the insurer as they will be able to recoup some small part of the value by selling the car as a write off.
Am I entitled to get the vehicle repaired and require the other party/their insurer to pay the costs of the repair or can the insurer force me to accept market value and take my vehicle?    What law/type of law covers this kind of issue?  (I suspect this is tort law but have not been able to find any concrete information on this)

I can't answer for New Zealand, but this has happened to me a couple times and in each case I have been given the option to accept full value and surrender the car, or accept full value minus the salvage value and keep the car.  Not sure if this is a right under any law, but the insurance companies have always been willing to do this.

How do you know that the vehicle will drive the same after its repairs, which, if you get to keep the vehicle, you will have to pay for? Sigh, draw a line, and move on. It's an inanimate object.

@WeatherVane  We have consumer protection laws in NZ - we would expect it to be repaired to an acceptable standard.   Again, I've simplified/fictionalized the question to help extract the relevant law/rights - my actual problem is a lot more nuanced (and this is not even my car).  I fully agree with your philosophy and I've already encouraged the injured party to "move on".

There may be a subtle misalignment which can't be adequately repaired. That has nothing to do with consumer protection. The insurance company has decreed that replacement is the only viable option.

@WeatherVane Thank you for engaging.  I don't believe the insurance company is  an arbiter of fact and they have not decreed anything - they have only offered a settlement which does not work for the injured party. (FWIW I have had advice from 2 repairers the car is structurally fine and can be repaired.  The insurance company has not even looked at the vehicle and are going off the report of my panel beaters.  No one was hurt in the accident)

@WeatherVane How does this line of questioning advance the discussion? As I understand it, OP is asking about the law governing a hypothetical transaction. Misdirecting the conversation to the mechanical implications of the collision doesn't illuminate anything that anyone is here to talk about.
